# Poi formula not getting evaluated correctly

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have a formula like this :

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*AM*",A1)) in column B.
```

After populating column A with:

```
cell.setCellValue("Smita AM D");
```

I call:

```
workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

The formula is not getting evaluated correctly. If I go to column B and click enter, the formula is evaluated correctly. I have tried setting `CELL_TYPE_STRING` to column A but no difference in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with Apache POI, it's actually with the formula! Specifically, with the wildcards, which shouldn't be there

You need to change your formula to instead be:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AM",A1))
```

As explained in the [Microsoft Excel function docs for Search](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/search-searchb-functions-HP010062577.aspx), the Search function takes a string to find, not a wildcard. Apache POI faithfully implements this

In [r1632842](http://svn.apache.org/r1632842) I have added unit tests to Apache POI which confirm that POI correctly evaluates the function `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AM",A1))`. All you need to do is give POI the right formula!

Comment: I tried with an older version, and it didn't find them with the `*` there

Comment: @smitamallik Glad it worked! Don't forget to accept the answer to let everyone else know this was the solution - see the [site tour in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on this and how the site works